# Pressure drop in a constricted tube

Tags: fluid-dynamics

According to Pascal'a law , pressure is transmitted equally throughout the fluid. But why is that the pressure decreases in a pipe at constriction?

Comment: For applicability of Pascal's law fluid should be confined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gas velocity increases at a constriction and due to Bernoulli's equation, we observe a pressure drop with a higher velocity. From continuity we have, 
$$ V_2 = \frac{A_1}{A_2} V_1 $$

Thus, if $A_1/A_2 > 1$ (constriction) then $V_2 > V_1$. Moreover, from the Bernoulli equation we have,

$$ p_2 = p_1 + \frac{1}{2} \rho \left(V_1^2 - V_2^2\right) $$

Since $V_1^2 - V_2^2 <0$, then $p_2 < p_1$. Note, all of this assumes steady, incompressible, and inviscid flow. Also, Pascal's law is concerned with a static fluid, but the problem you are describing is a fluid in motion.